# Robot не может получить цвет в игре

Tags: java

В игре *Crysis 3* (и почти во всех полно-экранных играх) пытаюсь получить цвет пикселя, в координате, рядом с курсором:

```
robot = new Robot(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice());
System.out.println(robot.getPixelColor(
    (int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() + 10,
    (int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() + 10
));
```

На что получаю сообщение:

```
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
```

Хотя в других играх\окнах выводиться правильный цвет. В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: а вы попробуйте скрин экрана сделать, он чёрный будет. Вроде бы это всё не работает если приложение идёт через DirectX или другой движок который переопределяет отрисовку кадров. Там нужно сложнее делать.

Comment: @pavel, возможно.. А почему в оконном режиме все работает?

Answer (score 0):

Делай всё это в

> оконном режиме

или в режиме

> окно без рамок

Иначе он будет делать скриншот чёрного экрана